# can we make horizontal scroll view infinte or loop around

Tags: android, android-view, horizontal-scrolling

I want to make horizontal scroll view infinite or atleast give the effect of being infinite.
Any idea how to do so?
can we listen to android horizontal scroll view as to when screen is scrolled.Is there any callback method that is called?

Can we know if the end of scroll has been reached?